# How do I compute a field value in a Lotus Notes/Domino form

Tags: lotus-domino, lotus

"Rinka" - field type "checkbox"
"Vadybininkas" - field type "text"

I want: if "Rinka" is selected `"First"` when in field vadybininkas will be `"Pirmas"`

I want: if "Rinka" is selected `"Second"` when in field vadybininkas will be `"Antras"`

I want: if "Rinka" is selected `"Third"` when in field vadybininkas will be `"Trečias"`

My code: `@If(Rinka='First'; 'Pirmas'; Rinka='Second';'Antras'; Rinka='Third';'Trecias'; NULL)`

But this if statment not work I plaece this code in `"Default value"`, but field `"Vadybininkas"` is still empty, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default value is only calculated ONCE when the document is opened. You need to change your field "Vadybininkas" to "Computed" and put this formula in the "Value"- Section.

In addition you need to tick the property "Refresh fields on Keyword change" for the Rinka- Field or set the "Automatically Refresh Fields"- Property of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Also NULL is not defined in Notes, it will interpret NULL as a non allocated variable name which will have the default value of "" (empty string).  NULL is not a defined state in Notes.  Just a point but worth knowing!